# TortoiseSVN: How can I commit my changes into an edited file?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm still learning the details of Tortoise SVN, but I'm unsure of how to commit my changes into a file someone else modified as well.

I retrieved a file from my company's svn repository & made changes to it.  During this time, someone else pulled the file also, made changes to it, and committed it back into the repository.  Now, I need to somehow commit only my lines of code within the file, without affecting his.  What's the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: you have to pull his change if there is a conflict you will have to merge the changes at your best knowledge. Good luck!

Comment: TortoiseSVN is just a handy GUI for Subversion. I suggest you have a look at the [The copy-modify-merge solution](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html#svn.basic.vsn-models.copy-merge) chapter in the Subversion book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain it simply, your file and his file are connected to a central location and you simply have to merge his changes into yours.

With TortoiseSVN, it's very simple, all you need to do is run an `svn update` (Right click on the file or checkout folder and click **SVN update**) on the file that the other developer modified, and SVN will then merge his changes into your working copy.

If there are merge conflicts because you two are working on the same parts of a file, then you can resolve them by using TortoiseSVN's built in merge tool. Subversion is typically pretty good at handling merges so if the changes are small/simple, you should be fine. However if they arise, you will simply have to right click on the file and click TortoiseSVN > Edit Conflicts.

Subversion won't let you commit to the repository if your file is not up to date. This means in order for you "affect" his changes would be to physically remove them from your file and then commit them to the repository.

---

One caveat to doing svn updates is if the file in question is a binary file (like a Word document or something similar). Binary file merges are typically overwrites so it might be in your best interest to copy and save your changes elsewhere before the merge.